# Cacheing a modal view with a map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, presentmodalviewcontroller

Using a UITabbarController, the views in each tab are not removed and reloaded when going from tab to tab. If tab 1 has a map, going to tab 2 and then back to tab 1, you would see the same map.

Is there a way to do this with a modal view with a map - shown with presentmodalviewcontroller - so that the view does not get removed and recreated each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't release your ViewController which contains the map after you present it modally but rather reuse it again. It's not quite memory effective, but it's the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just init your mapViewController with the same coordinate and mask region so it shows the same location each time ?

```
MyMapViewController *map = [[MyMapViewController alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude Longitude:longitude];

[self presentModalViewController:map animated:YES];

[map release];
```

Comment: there are many annotations on the map, so it's not just a case of setting region & coordinates.